# How to know when push is opened; Azure Push Notifications Notification Hub?

Tags: java, android, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have implemented push notifications using Azure's Notification Hub. I have noticed that they only have three override methods when extending NotificationHandler:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Bundle bundle)

public void onUnregistered(Context context, String gcmRegistrationId)

public void onRegistered(Context context, String gcmRegistrationId)
```

Most push notification services have an onPushOpen() or onOpen() callback method which is called when a user presses on the push notification they received. How do I know when someone has clicked on the received push notification? I am experimenting with the demo. Everything works minus the concern I have said.

Link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/blob/master/Android/GetStartedFirebase/app/src/main/java/com/example/microsoft/getstartednh/MyHandler.java

```
public class MyHandler extends NotificationsHandler {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
        ctx = context;
        String nhMessage = bundle.getString("message");
        sendNotification(nhMessage);
        if (MainActivity.isVisible) {
            MainActivity.mainActivity.ToastNotify(nhMessage);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Notification Hub Demo")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to figure this out, it is actually pretty simple. In the sendNotification() method, whatever information you want to keep track of when the push notification is opened add it as extras to your intent. For example.

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // seeking to do something specific when notification is opened if flag is set 
        intent.putExtra("onPushOpen", "performSomeAction");

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Notification Hub Demo") 
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Now that you have done this. In onResume() check for that information. It will be empty (null) when push notification is not invoked, otherwise, it will have your information.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
// now retrieve what you want from the bundle.
```